# Passing database variable through url how secure

Tags: php, mysql

Please I am designing a website and passed two IDs to through URL and got it using GET .But I noticed that anyone could change the value of ID in the URL and it alters the page content. Is there anyway to prevent this ...
 A code like

```
www. site.com/main.php?user1_id=4&user2_id=7
```

If changed by anybody to

```
www.site.com/main.php?user1_id=6&user2_id=10
```

It shows another detail not meant to be seen.

Comment: use method `post`instead of `get`

Comment: No, there is no way to stop this. Even with POST people can still mangle the data before sending. You need to validate whatever input you get, confirm access rights to what they've requested.

Comment: So, there are users who are allowed to see details and users (or guests) who are not allowed to see the details? Yeah, you can't do this without coding at least a minimal right and privilege system

Comment: You should consider that anyone could create any `URL` then `GET` it on your site. You could sanitize the parameters but you can not control what that parameters are.

Comment: If you need to restrict something to someone that someone will need to provide valid credentials that they are indeed the person who is allowed to see that something. Countless of tutorials on how to do this out there.

Answer (score 1):

Implement control at server side and check if the user requesting the resource has access to it or not. Anyone can change anything at client side easily. This should be controlled from server.

Comment: Okk..Thanks alot for your responses..That's true anyone can change anything on client side